# how do I retrieve objects from an array to create a whole new arry

Tags: arrays, new-operator

I have an array that looks like this.

```
0:{9 items
"id":"380721"
"group":""
"po_type":NULL
"team1short":"TOR"
"team1long":"Toronto"
"team2short":"OTT"
"team2long":"Ottawa"
"date":"2019-10-03 01:00:00"
"score":{...}3 items
}
1:{9 items
"id":"380731"
"group":""
"po_type":NULL
"team1short":"STL"
"team1long":"St. Louis"
"team2short":"WSH"
"team2long":"Washington"
"date":"2019-10-03 02:00:00"
"score":{...}3 items
}
2:{9 items
"id":"380741"
"group":""
"po_type":NULL
"team1short":"EDM"
"team1long":"Edmonton"
"team2short":"VAN"
"team2long":"Vancouver"
"date":"2019-10-03 04:00:00"
"score":{...}3 items
}
3:{9 items
"id":"380751"
"group":""
"po_type":NULL
"team1short":"VGK"
"team1long":"Vegas"
"team2short":"SJS"
"team2long":"San Jose"
"date":"2019-10-03 04:30:00"
"score":{...}3 items
}
4:{9 items
"id":"380761"
"group":""
"po_type":NULL
"team1short":"TBL"
"team1long":"Tampa Bay"
"team2short":"FLA"
"team2long":"Florida"
"date":"2019-10-04 01:00:00"
"score":{...}3 items
}
```

Newbie here.  This array goes on for duration of a hockey season.  I can not for the life of me figure out how to create a new array with games that only contain team1long = Toronto.  You can find this in this at games[0]

Any help would stop me from banging my head against the wall relentlessly!

this is the code I was using to loop through all the games.  javascript

```
<% for (i = 0; i <games1.games.length; i++) { %>
<tr>
    <th scope="row"><%= games1.games[i].date %></th>
        <th><%= games1.games[i].team1long %></th>
        <td><%= games1.games[i].score.goals1 %></td>
        <td><%= games1.games[i].team2long %></td>
        <td><%= games1.games[i].score.goals2 %></td>
</tr>   
<% } %>
```

That was working just fine.

I was trying to run with something like this to create a new arry.

```
game[] gamesFromToronto;

For(i=0 ; i < games.Length ; i++)
{
 if(games[i].team1Long == “Toronto”)
{
gamesFromToronto[gamesFromToronto.length] = games[i];
}
}
```

Comment: please provide some more information. in which language you want to do that? and give a brave example and your code ...

Comment: So is everyone as stumped as I am?

Comment: check my answer bellow

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your code, the logic is correct and should work. But... you made so many mistakes in your code (syntax error and spelling code error) like you start a lot of things with an Uppercase instead of lowercase like :

```
For --> should be --> for
team1Long  --> should be --> team1long  ( l and not L ) 
“Toronto” --> should be --> "Toronto" ( " and not “ ) 
gamesFromToronto[gamesFromToronto.length] = games[i];  --> should be --> gamesFromToronto.push(games[i]);
```

so here is a working code that works correctly :

```
//solution 
var gamesFromToronto = [];

for (i=0 ; i < games.length ; i++ ) {
     if(games[i].team1long == "Toronto"){
        gamesFromToronto.push(games[i]);
    }
}
```

for tests :

```js
//data sample
 games = [
{
"id":"380721",
"group":"",
"po_type":null,
"team1short":"TOR",
"team1long":"Toronto",
"team2short":"OTT",
"team2long":"Ottawa",
"date":"2019-10-03 01:00:00"
},
{
"id":"380731",
"group":"",
"po_type":null,
"team1short":"STL",
"team1long":"St. Louis",
"team2short":"WSH",
"team2long":"Washington",
"date":"2019-10-03 02:00:00"
},
{
"id":"380741",
"group":"",
"po_type":null,
"team1short":"EDM",
"team1long":"Toronto",
"team2short":"VAN",
"team2long":"Vancouver",
"date":"2019-10-03 04:00:00"
},
{
"id":"380731",
"group":"",
"po_type":null,
"team1short":"STL",
"team1long":"St. Louis",
"team2short":"WSH",
"team2long":"Washington",
"date":"2019-10-03 02:00:00"
},
{
"id":"380731",
"group":"",
"po_type":null,
"team1short":"STL",
"team1long":"St. Louis",
"team2short":"WSH",
"team2long":"Washington",
"date":"2019-10-03 02:00:00"
}] ; 

//solution 
var gamesFromToronto = [];

for (i=0 ; i < games.length ; i++ ) {
  if(games[i].team1long == "Toronto"){
  gamesFromToronto.push(games[i]);
 }
}
//visualisation
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(gamesFromToronto);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Your welcome accept the answer so to help others tooo thanks